# Combine Mail Merge with printing different word files depending on cell value?

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

**Context:**

I have a excel sheet with the address and contacts of customers and the product they purchased.

I use Mail Merge to insert the address and names of the customers to word in the format I wish and then print it for shipping.

**The actual problem:**

We have many different products and to every product we have a specific description. With every order I want to include the description. How can I use mail merge to print the address and name of the customer and in the same moment also the description of the product on the second page?

- Every product has a unique and specific product number.
- To every product there is a description, labelled with the product
  number.
- Every description is in a separate Word file.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: As it stands, this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Mail Merge is an end-user functionality; Stack Overflow is for programming issues. The more correct place to ask end-user questions is Super User or the Microsoft Answers Community. I can point you to my web-site and the topic "Multiple items per condition" to give you an overview of possible ways to go about this: http://homepage.swissonline.ch/cindymeister/MergFram.htm

Comment: The simple answer is to use an INCLUDETEXT field in which the filename is replaced by a mergefield referencing the product name in your data source. Depending on how many entries there are per customer, the implementation could be considerably more complex than that. As Cindy says, not really a question for Stack Overflow.